# Proving the reccuring pattern of $60^n\equiv1,4,2 \mod 7$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, induction

By simple trial and error I stumbled upon:
$60^0\equiv1 \mod 7$
$60^1\equiv4\mod 7$
$60^2\equiv2 \mod 7$
$60^3\equiv1 \mod 7$
$60^4\equiv4\mod 7$
$60^5\equiv2 \mod 7$
...

This goes on forever. Well maybe, that's the thing I have no idea how you would prove this.

I suppose induction is possible but what are the base cases here?

Comment: $\bmod 7\!:\ 60\equiv 2^2\,$ so $\,60^{\bf \large \color{#c00}3}\equiv 2^6\equiv 1\,$ by the [Congruence Power Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242) and Fermat's little Theorem, so  we deduce $\,60^{\large n}\equiv 60^{\bf\large n\bmod\color{#c00} 3}\,$ by [mod order reduction](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2033681/242) in the linked dupe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all $60\equiv4\pmod 7$ as $56$ is divisible by $7$.

Now if you actually know [Fermat's Little Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) then you would see that for any integer $a$ coprime to a prime number $p$. You have $a^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod p$.

So $4^{7}\equiv 4^{6}\cdot 4\pmod 7\equiv 1\cdot 4\pmod 7 \equiv4\pmod 7$ and so the pattern continues and after each multiple of $6$ you will get back the same integer.
So it suffices to show that the first $6$ powers are like that. Then the pattern holds for all integers .

Maybe you can take a look at some basic modular arithmetic to make things clearer. Maybe someday you will also learn group theory and cyclic groups. Maybe someday you will  get to learn about [Euler's Totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function) or [Carmichael's Lambda Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function)

Comment: Please strive not to add more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).